# How did Zebulun become experts and experienced in War? 1 Chronicles 12:33

Tags: hebrew

How did Zebulun become experts and experienced in War? 1 Chronicles 12:33

In the Hebrew is expert / experienced the best word translation from the text?

Comment: Please quote the verse that you cite and indicate which translation you are using.

Comment: As it is now it is very hard to know which word you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the verse section Mitch Belfast refers is the first (1Ch 12:33 [12:34]): **מזבלון יוצאי צבא ערכי מלחמה**. The terms he may refers are צבא and/or ערכי.
The first (צבא) is often translate '*army*', the second (ערכי) '*troops*', or '*formation*'. Maybe, this last term may permit some equivocalities, since the Strong (the bold is mine) affirms it means: "[...] *to set in a row, that is, arrange, put in order (in a very wide variety of applications): - put (set) (the battle, self) in array, compare, direct, equal, esteem, estimate, **expert [in war]**, furnish, handle, join [battle], ordain, (lay, put, reckon up, set) (in) order, prepare, tax, value*."
At any rate, to have a complete view of the meaning of this term we have to ascertain the basilar concept of it. For example, if we think this term does possess the basilar concept revolved around the idea of 'expertise' we cannot will be able to apply this concept to others occurrence of this term (Exo 40:4, Num 18:26; 2 Kin 23:35, et al.). Interestingly, the often keen linguist Parkhurst sustained that some modern words are derivative terms of ערך: '*rectus*' (Latin), then, '*rectitude*', '*rectify*' (English), and "*by transposition*", '*rank*', '*range*', whence '*arrange*', *&c*," [John Parkhurst's *Hebrew and English Lexicon*, under ערך]. Actually, the basilar concept behind ערך [*ORK*] is '**to set in strict order**', '**to dispose in an accurate arrange**', like a well formed '*orch*estra'.

Obviously, if those 50,000 Zabulonites were able to form an army capable to keep ranks they did possess some expertise... But to me, **a translation of ערך that includes a *specific* concept of "expert/experienced" isn't present in this root**.